# Why is the correct action not triggering while dispatching?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-thunk

Action

```
export const VERIFY = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: "VERIFY"})
};
```

Reducer

```
const signedReducer = (state=user, action) => {
    console.log(action);

    switch(action.type){
     
        case "VERIFY": {
            return {...state, email: "example@gmail.com"};
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }

}
```

`_app.js` code

```
import { wrapper } from '../redux/store';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return <>
    <Component {...pageProps}/>
  </>
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async(appContext) => {
  let { pageProps } = appContext
    pageProps = {};
    if(appContext.Component.getInitialProps){
     
      pageProps = await appContext.Component.getInitialProps(appContext.ctx);
    }

    return {
      pageProps,
 
    };
};

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

& finally `pages/home.js`

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import PrivateLayout from "../components/PrivateLayout/PrivateLayout";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { VERIFY } from "../redux/actions/signActions";

function Home() {
  // console.log(user);

  // useEffect(() => {

  // }, [user]);

  
  return (
      <div >
        { true ? 
            <h1>Logged In</h1> 
                  : 
            <h1>Please login again</h1>
        }
      </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  VERIFY: VERIFY
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Please check, I've put an console.log statement in the reducer.
Whenever I run the code the console.log statement display these action type only

- @@redux/INIT6.z.d.a.h.7
- @@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTIONq.x.h.3.5.d

But never takes the action `VERIFY`.
Looked across the internet but haven't found any solution regarding this. Why?

Comment: At what point do you want to call the action? Because I don't see any action call in your **Home** component.

Comment: When the page is opened or redirected from other page, I want the action to be triggered. I was thinking that action will be triggered with this. Please give an example how to trigger.

Comment: @Ammar You are right, thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

Also you need to call VERIFY in your component.

Action:

```
export const VERIFY = () => ({type: "VERIFY"});
```

reference: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch